# Rails 4 - Display data inside a bootstrap modal via ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a pretty simple Ruby On Rails app with bootstrap 3 for the front end: I have Deals, and each Deal has_many Opportunities.

On each Deal page (url of deal 1 is like myapp.com/id=1), I want to have a textual link that says "view deal's opportunities" and that must trigger when clicked the appearance of content inside a Bootstrap modal.

**Very basic but for specific reasons, I wish to load the content of the modal via Ajax.**(the content is not visible when users load the Deal page but only when they click on the link 'view deal's opportunities'

I found many resources online for Rails4/ajax/Forms and other stuff with Ajax but not a simple "display content/text" inside a modal via Ajax. Should be easy but I'm stuck.

**controller/deals_controller.rb**

```
def showcase    
    deals = Deal.friendly.find(params[:id])   

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # showcase.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @deal }
    end
end 

def show_opportunities

    @opportunities = Opportunity.where('deal_id = ? AND deal_type = ?',
                             @deal.id, "high tech").first

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end

  end
```

**app/views/deals/showcase.html.erb**

```
this is the beginning
<%= render 'deals/deal_info_zone' %>
this is the end
```

**views/deals/_deal_info_zone.html.erb**

```
<div id="zoneA">  

  <div style="color:red;padding-top: 150px;">
    <%= link_to "view infos of Opportunities", deal_opportunities_modal_path, remote: true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the modal I'd like to trigger via ajax: views/deals/opportunity_moda**l

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body"> 

          <%= @opportunity.name %> <br/>     

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
match '/deals/:id', # this is the Deal page
    to:   'deals#showcase',
    via:  'get',
    as:   :deal_page

match '/opportunity_modal',
    to:   'deals#show_opportunities',
    via:  'get',
    as:   :deal_opportunities_modal
```

I'm a rookie in RoR and have never used  ajax, ujs maybe... I feel it's missing things like javascript code and xhr request...

The current situation is this one: when I go on a Deal page (for ex page /deal id=1) the textual link "view infos of Opportunities". and the browser points to http://localhost:3000/opportunity_modal but it does not trigger anything when I click on it. Nothing happens. Nothing gets displayed btw on firebug console.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary to "thanks", nor is it particularly desirable. SO is more of a reference book than a bulletin board or conversation. Use **bold** text very carefully. It's very much akin to YELLING. Look around and notice the common look of questions and answers and mimic that.

Comment: dully noted. will adjust the question and my future ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click a `remote: true` link, rails is not looking for `opportunity_modal.html.erb`, it's looking for `opportunity_modal.js.erb`. What you need to to do is put your modal in a partial, then render it with JavaScript.

1. Put your modal code into  a partial named `views/deals/_opportunity_modal.html.erb`.
2. Create a `views/deals/opportunity_modal.js.erb` file that will render and show the modal when the this action is triggered.

```
$('body').append('<%= j render partial: "views/deals/opportunity_modal" %>');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Also, you have a variable `@opportunity` in the modal, but it's not defined in your controller, so make sure to define that as well.

Comment: Great thanks it worked. Just before accepting the answer,a complementary isue: you did not use "request.xhr": I run acros many examples of Rails/ajax where they use inside "def show_opportunities "something like "if request.xhr? respond_to do |format| format.js..." Is is useful to add this thing? maybe for security or speed performance?

Comment: Typically you would have a respond_to block in the controller with format.js { } and other formats. This allows your controller to respond to different requests, so if you have another link that is not remote, you can render html, json, xml, etc. Using 'if request.xhr?' is unnecessary, as rails already knows it's xhr when you use the remote: true helper.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. makes sense

Comment: I just posted another question because there was 2 issues: you solved the first one :; now I can see the modal appear with content but inside this content if I try to put data related to Opportunity like <%= @opportunity.name %>, it does not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782803/rails-4-ajax-nomethoderror-undefined-method-id-for-nilnilclass-passign